# Playing audio files with jPlayer from a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jplayer

I have a large project that generates a list of music files for a user and I want to use an instance of jPlayer to play a file when the  it is in gets clicked on.

Currently, this is the code at the head of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3" //test file
            });
        },
        ended: function (event) {   
            $(this).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3"
    });
```

This is just the code for loading the initial file, and it works completely.

Also at the head, I have this block that changes the current file when a row gets clicked. It gets the md5 hash that's set as the id on the row and passes it to a php file which returns the file path. I've checked this with firebug and it seems to be returning a valid path.

```
    $("tr").click(function() {      
        var md5 = $(this).attr("id");
        var filename = "";
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                filename = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","md5tofilename.php?md5="+md5,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: filename           
        });
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");
        return false;
    });
});
```

For whatever reason, clicking a row does not cause the new file to play, although it does unset the current file. jPlayer sets the time to '0:00' and acts like there is no file loaded.

For reference, here is an example of a generated row:

```
<tr id="bbac3c5090c5ca76ce7a02b8112dec0a" class="row1">
    ...
</tr>
```

And the response from calling the php file for a test value:

```
GET http://localhost/md5tofilename.php?md5=1234567890 200 OK 36ms   

"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3"
```

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong or what's causing the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After setting the media and then trying to play on the following line the plugin will not be ready yet to play. Try something like this to attempt to auto-play.

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: filename           
}).jPlayer("play"); // Attempts to Auto-Play the media
```